# How to set a Default Program and include a parameter switch?

Tags: windows, windows-10, file-association, sharex

How would I add a parameter to the default program that I’m wanting to set?

I love the ShareX image editor and I would like to make it the default image editor for Windows 10.

However, when I select the ShareX.exe process, it just processes the image like it would a normal capture instead of opening the image editor.

Instead, There is the **-imageeditor “file path”** command.

How would I set **“C:\Program Files\ShareX\ShareX.exe” -imageeditor** as the default handler for image files?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a tool like Default Programs Editor to do the job:
https://defaultprogramseditor.com/

1. First, Select "File Type Settings".
2. Then select "Context Menu".
3. Now in the search box type the file extension of the image file, e.g. ".png" and click `Next`
4. Click on "Edit" in the list and click `Edit Selected Command` at the bottom.
5. Now, in the "Program Path" box type in the following: `"C:\Program Files\ShareX\ShareX.exe" -imageeditor "%1"`
6. Click `Next` and then click `Save Context Menu`

Now whenever you right-click a png file (or whichever file extensions you did the above steps for) and click "Edit" it should open up with the ShareX editor.

Comment: That worked! Thank you! It Also opens with it by double-clicking and anything.